# Reactive Data Frame in Shiny Leaflet Map

Tags: r, shiny, leaflet

I'm attempting to create a `leaflet` map in `shiny` that adjusts and possibly recalculates my data in different ways depending on a `selectInput` in the `ui`.

My data is stored as a `data.frame` similar to this:

```
data <- data.frame(County.FIPS=c(19191,19191,19013,31055,17161,19019), Profit=c(250000,5000000,150000,300000,2000000,0), Type=c("Marketing", "Sales","Online","Marketing","Marketing","Sales"))
```

What I then do is aggregate the data by `County.FIPS` and then geo_join it to shapefiles of the county boundaries in Minnesota, Iowa, and Nebraska.

```
library(tigris)
library(leaflet)

data <- data[complete.cases(data),]
county <-aggregate(data$Profit~data$County.FIPS,data=data,sum)
colnames(county) <- c("GEOID","Profit")

IA_counties <- counties(state="IA", cb=TRUE, resolution ="20m")
MN_counties <- counties(state="MN",cb=TRUE,resolution="20m")
NE_counties <- counties(state="NE",cb=TRUE,resolution="20m")
IA_merged <- geo_join(IA_counties,county,"GEOID", "GEOID")
MN_merged <- geo_join(MN_counties,county,"GEOID","GEOID")
NE_merged <- geo_join(NE_counties,county,"GEOID","GEOID")
popupIA <- paste0("County Projects: ", as.character(paste('$',formatC(format(round(IA_merged$Profit, 0), big.mark=',', format = 'f')))))
popupMN <- paste0("County Projects: ", as.character(paste('$',formatC(format(round(MN_merged$Profit, 0), big.mark=',', format = 'f')))))
popupNE <- paste0("County Projects: ", as.character(paste('$',formatC(format(round(NE_merged$Profit, 0), big.mark=',', format = 'f')))))
```

This is the part where I'm not sure if I'm doing things correctly/ideally and I don't know how to go on from here. **What I would like to do is create a reactive `data.frame` where my map is redrawn whenever my drop down selection changes from "Marketing" to "Online" to "Sales" or "All".** I have previously tried to save my three different data.frames as separate RData (Marketing.RData, Online.RData, Sales.RData, All.RData) to call on, but I figure there has to be a better way. Here is what I have so far...

`ui.r`

```
library(shiny)
library(leaflet)
library(tigris)

ui <- bootstrapPage(
  tags$style(type = "text/css", "html, body {width:100%;height:100%}"),
  leafletOutput("map",width="100%",height="100%"),
  absolutePanel(top=10,right=10,
                selectInput("type", label = h5("Type of Projects:"), choices=list("Marketing"=1, "Sales"=2, "Online"=3,"All"=4,selected =1)
                ))
)
```

`server.r`

```
server <- function(input, output, session) {

  filteredData <- reactive({
    if(input$type=="1"){
      load("Marketing.RData")
      IA_counties <- counties(state="IA", cb=TRUE, resolution ="20m")
      MN_counties <- counties(state="MN",cb=TRUE,resolution="20m")
      NE_counties <- counties(state="NE",cb=TRUE,resolution="20m")
      IA_merged <- geo_join(IA_counties,county,"GEOID", "GEOID")
      MN_merged <- geo_join(MN_counties,county,"GEOID","GEOID")
      NE_merged <- geo_join(NE_counties,county,"GEOID","GEOID")
      popupIA <- paste0("County Projects: ", as.character(paste('$',formatC(format(round(IA_merged$Profit, 0), big.mark=',', format = 'f')))))
      popupMN <- paste0("County Projects: ", as.character(paste('$',formatC(format(round(MN_merged$Profit, 0), big.mark=',', format = 'f')))))
      popupNE <- paste0("County Projects: ", as.character(paste('$',formatC(format(round(NE_merged$Profit, 0), big.mark=',', format = 'f')))))
      pal <- colorNumeric(c("gray","dark green"),county$Profit,na.color="white")
    }
    else if(input$type=="2"){
      load("Sales.RData")
      IA_counties <- counties(state="IA", cb=TRUE, resolution ="20m")
      MN_counties <- counties(state="MN",cb=TRUE,resolution="20m")
      NE_counties <- counties(state="NE",cb=TRUE,resolution="20m")
      IA_merged <- geo_join(IA_counties,county,"GEOID", "GEOID")
      MN_merged <- geo_join(MN_counties,county,"GEOID","GEOID")
      NE_merged <- geo_join(NE_counties,county,"GEOID","GEOID")
      popupIA <- paste0("County Projects: ", as.character(paste('$',formatC(format(round(IA_merged$Profit, 0), big.mark=',', format = 'f')))))
      popupMN <- paste0("County Projects: ", as.character(paste('$',formatC(format(round(MN_merged$Profit, 0), big.mark=',', format = 'f')))))
      popupNE <- paste0("County Projects: ", as.character(paste('$',formatC(format(round(NE_merged$Profit, 0), big.mark=',', format = 'f')))))
      pal <- colorNumeric(c("gray","dark green"),county$Profit,na.color="white")
     }
    else if(input$type=="3"){
      load("Online.RData")
      IA_counties <- counties(state="IA", cb=TRUE, resolution ="20m")
      MN_counties <- counties(state="MN",cb=TRUE,resolution="20m")
      NE_counties <- counties(state="NE",cb=TRUE,resolution="20m")
      IA_merged <- geo_join(IA_counties,county,"GEOID", "GEOID")
      MN_merged <- geo_join(MN_counties,county,"GEOID","GEOID")
      NE_merged <- geo_join(NE_counties,county,"GEOID","GEOID")
      popupIA <- paste0("County Projects: ", as.character(paste('$',formatC(format(round(IA_merged$Profit, 0), big.mark=',', format = 'f')))))
      popupMN <- paste0("County Projects: ", as.character(paste('$',formatC(format(round(MN_merged$Profit, 0), big.mark=',', format = 'f')))))
      popupNE <- paste0("County Projects: ", as.character(paste('$',formatC(format(round(NE_merged$Profit, 0), big.mark=',', format = 'f')))))
      pal <- colorNumeric(c("gray","dark green"),county$Profit,na.color="white")
     }
else if(input$type=="4"){
          load("All.RData")
          IA_counties <- counties(state="IA", cb=TRUE, resolution ="20m")
          MN_counties <- counties(state="MN",cb=TRUE,resolution="20m")
          NE_counties <- counties(state="NE",cb=TRUE,resolution="20m")
          IA_merged <- geo_join(IA_counties,county,"GEOID", "GEOID")
          MN_merged <- geo_join(MN_counties,county,"GEOID","GEOID")
          NE_merged <- geo_join(NE_counties,county,"GEOID","GEOID")
          popupIA <- paste0("County Projects: ", as.character(paste('$',formatC(format(round(IA_merged$Profit, 0), big.mark=',', format = 'f')))))
          popupMN <- paste0("County Projects: ", as.character(paste('$',formatC(format(round(MN_merged$Profit, 0), big.mark=',', format = 'f')))))
          popupNE <- paste0("County Projects: ", as.character(paste('$',formatC(format(round(NE_merged$Profit, 0), big.mark=',', format = 'f')))))
          pal <- colorNumeric(c("gray","dark green"),county$Profit,na.color="white")
         }
      })
      output$map <- renderLeaflet({
        leaflet() %>%
          addProviderTiles("Esri.WorldStreetMap") %>%
          addLegend(pal = pal, 
                    values = IA_merged$Profit, 
                    position = "bottomright", 
                    title = "County Projects",
                    labFormat=labelFormat(prefix="$")) %>%
          addCircles(lng=yup$lon, lat=yup$lat,weight=1,fillOpacity=0.05,color="red",
                     radius = 96560) %>%
          addCircles(lng=yup$lon, lat=yup$lat,weight=1,fillOpacity=0.025,color="blue",
                     radius = 193121)
      })

      observe({
        leafletProxy("map",data=filteredData()) %>%
          clearShapes() %>%
          addPolygons(data = IA_counties, 
                      fillColor = ~pal(IA_merged$Profit), 
                      fillOpacity = .25, 
                      weight = 0.05, 
                      popup = popupIA)%>%
          addPolygons(data=MN_counties,
                      fillColor=~pal(MN_merged$Profit),
                      fillOpacity=0.25,
                      weight=0.05, 
                      popup = popupMN) %>%
          addPolygons(data=NE_counties,
                      fillColor=~pal(NE_merged$Profit),
                      fillOpacity=0.25,
                      weight=0.05, 
                      popup = popupNE) 
      })



}
```

Currently, when I run this my map works, but the map slowly reloads and re-runs all the `counties()` functions, which takes a while and also doesn't change my values of Profit by county in the maps. They all show the "All.RData" numbers.

Thanks to any and all help and please, let me know if you need anything clarified or have any questions!

Comment: so you want your polygons to display "Marketing", "Sales","Online", or "All" according to your drop down selection? I am not sure if it would be faster but maybe you could try using Groups (https://rstudio.github.io/leaflet/showhide.html). You would have four layers of polygons but only one will be displayed. After you can click/unclick the one you want. I have used groups (with points though...) before and the map load much faster.

Comment: So, I think your solution is leading me down the right track for an answer. My question is if I use groups, am I able to still make the legend recalculate its values using `leafletProxy()` or do I need to just manually set all `colorNumeric` values to the same scale?

Comment: good point, I forgot about the legend. I hope I am wrong but I think you will have to manually set all colorNumeric values to the same scale. I tried before to have two legends but never found a way to make it work.